# Get File Size On An FTP in C#

Tags: c#, ftp, size

I want to get the size of a file on an FTP.

```
        //Get File Size
        reqSize = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(FtpPath + filePath));
        reqSize.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
        reqSize.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
        reqSize.UseBinary = true;
        FtpWebResponse respSize = (FtpWebResponse)reqSize.GetResponse();
        long size = respSize.ContentLength;
        respSize.Close();
```

I have tried the following but get a 550 error.  File not found / no access.  However, the following code works...

```
                reqTime = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(FtpPath + filePath));
                reqTime.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
                reqTime.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
                reqTime.UseBinary = true;
                FtpWebResponse respTime = (FtpWebResponse)reqTime.GetResponse();
                DateTime LastModified = respTime.LastModified;
                respTime.Close();
```

**EDIT: The reason this isn't working for me is that my FTP Server does not support the SIZE method.**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try `reqSize.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;`
instead of GetDateTimestamp

This worked for me:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://servername/filepath"));
request.Proxy = null;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
long size = response.ContentLength;
response.Close();
```

Comment: Better comment than previous: He needs to read the data from the response, not just get the `ContentLength`, I believe. Either way, it seems odd the contentlength would be 0.

Comment: That was a copy paste error - I updated my question with much more detail.

Comment: I CAN get the file size without downloading the file right?  I just dont want to download this file, since its huge, if its the same size locally.

Comment: I think it may be because SIZE isn't implemented on the FTP Server, based on some googling. I am going to check it out.

Comment: @Andrew Barber - I don't think he wants to read data from the response, he just wants the ContentLength (which is the length of the file)

Comment: @IDWMaster: I know, but that behavior just seems odd to me. If you are requesting the file size, shouldn't that be the data being returned?

Comment: No, it seems to work (at least on my computer) without reading any data from the response.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd GetResponse() should be omitted. If I do three calls to GetResponse() all the responses are equal (compared with == in the immediate window). The result is in the loginresponse.ContentLength.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to get file size while downloading it.
Both, given answers doesn't work for me, so I made this, using StatusDescription property of FtpWebResponse with DownloadFile method:

```
int openingBracket = response.StatusDescription.IndexOf("(");
int closingBracket = response.StatusDescription.IndexOf(")");                     
var temporarySubstring = response.StatusDescription.Substring(openingBracket+1, closingBracket - openingBracket);
var fileSize = temporarySubstring.Substring(0, temporarySubstring.IndexOf(" "));
```

I suppose there is better way to do this with RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

//Simplest and Efficient way to Get FTP File Size.

var size = GetFtpFileSize(new Uri("ftpURL"), new NetworkCredential("userName", "password"));

```
public static long GetFtpFileSize(Uri requestUri, NetworkCredential networkCredential)
{
    //Create ftpWebRequest object with given options to get the File Size. 
    var ftpWebRequest = GetFtpWebRequest(requestUri, networkCredential, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize);

    try { return ((FtpWebResponse)ftpWebRequest.GetResponse()).ContentLength; } //Incase of success it'll return the File Size.
    catch (Exception) { return default(long); } //Incase of fail it'll return default value to check it later.
}
public static FtpWebRequest GetFtpWebRequest(Uri requestUri, NetworkCredential networkCredential, string method = null)
{
    var ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri); //Create FtpWebRequest with given Request Uri.
    ftpWebRequest.Credentials = networkCredential; //Set the Credentials of current FtpWebRequest.

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
        ftpWebRequest.Method = method; //Set the Method of FtpWebRequest incase it has a value.
    return ftpWebRequest; //Return the configured FtpWebRequest.
}
```