# C# Doesn't get file size on FTP Server

Tags: c#, ftp, filesize

When I want to get the size of a file on my ftp server I gets nothing.

Anyone see a problem in the code?

it seems to me that method is good

the class :

```
public string getFileSize(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + fileName);
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
        string fileInfo = null;
        try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { fileInfo = ftpReader.ReadToEnd(); } }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        ftpReader.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
        return fileInfo;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return "";
}
```

the process :

```
ftp ftpClientCheckFile = new ftp(@"ftp://******.******.fr", "***********", "********");
string ftpfileSize = ftpClientCheckFile.getFileSize(fileName);

if (ftpfileSize == localfilesize)
{
  this.Invoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(this, "*********", "***", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); }));
  ftpClientCheckFile = null;
}
else
{
  this.Invoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(this, "***** ", "*******", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); }));
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you certain the target server's FTP implementation supports that information? Don't think they all do.

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175874/get-file-size-on-an-ftp-in-c-sharp

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the ContentLength property to get the file size

```
Console.WriteLine(ftpResponse.ContentLength.ToString());
```

Some ftp servers don't support `getfilesize` so you will have to use `ListDirectoryDetails`