# ContentLength is returning as -1 when trying to download jpg from IIS ftp server

Tags: c#

When trying to download a file from local IIS ftp server, FtpWebResponse ConetentLength is returning as -1.

**IIS FTP configuration :**

1. **IP Unassigned** : All Unassigned
2. **SSL** : No ssl
3. **Authentication** : Anonymous
4. **Authorization** : All users
5. **Permission** : read,write

Below is my code,

```
string serverUris = "ftp://localhost//test.txt";
string localFileName = "D://"
Uri serverUri = new Uri(serverUris);
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = null;
StreamReader readStream = null;
StreamWriter writeStream = null;
try
{
    responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    Console.WriteLine("Bytes received: {0}",response.ContentLength);
    if (readStream != null)
    {
        writeStream = new StreamWriter(localFileName, false);
        writeStream.Write(readStream.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
finally
{
    if (readStream != null)
    {
        readStream.Close();
    }
    if (response != null)
    {
        response.Close();
    }
    if (writeStream != null)
    {
        writeStream.Close();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Bytes received: -1
```

Comment: A bigger problem is the fact that you're treating binary data as a string. [Here's a trivial example](https://rextester.com/HMG60126) of what kind of corruption that can lead to. I recommend using [`CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Stream_CopyTo_System_IO_Stream_) on the `Stream` itself, or manually reading/writing the data between the streams (not as a string!!!), adding up the bytes as you go.

Comment: Corrected the code. I was trying to download a text file

Comment: Same code was working when we used to connect to vendor's ftp. Not sure about what their ftp server was. But when we tried with our own local FTP it was not working. Not sure whether its IIS issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15026818/3181933 ?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it will help you a lot. Check out the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: @Llama that answer suggests using what is giving trouble to OP, probably not helpful. Looks more like IIS configuration. Check  [IIS Content Length is zero](https://serverfault.com/questions/115099/iis-content-length-0-for-css-javascript-and-images).

Comment: @Cleptus It also says _"Some ftp servers don't support getfilesize so you will have to use ListDirectoryDetails"_, which I thought might be _especially relevant_ to OP's situation. I haven't used IIS as an FTP server so perhaps it does support `ContentLength` - I don't know. What I do know is that not all FTP servers support it, and that answer provides a solution for servers that don't.

Comment: @Llama you're right. tried with vsftpd and it works like a charm