# How can I download files greater that 1MB from FTP using c#

Tags: c#, file, download, ftp

I have created a C# application for downloading file from FTP. I could not download files having size greater than 1 MB. I got an error "Data is corrupted" while downloading the file. Here is my code for download.

```
int count = 0;
do
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    conn.ReadTimeout = 15000000;
    count = istream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
} while (istream.CanRead && count > 0);

byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
var workBook = new XLWorkbook(memoryStream);
var workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
```

[image]

Comment: Increate the size of the Byte Array if you need to know how big to make it look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175874/get-file-size-on-an-ftp-in-c-sharp and make you byte array the required size

Comment: What is `conn`?  Also, the exception points at something off the screen.  Can we see what it's pointing at?

Comment: -1 Do not post screen shots of code. It makes it very hard for other users to try the code out. Be responsible and considerate and post the actual code as text for people who are answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an issue with firewall blocking from my system on uploading data to FTP server. The uploaded data is corrupted on the FTP server and I am trying to download the same corrupted data using my code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code that when you read data from istream and in there is no more data it will return count 0, and you need to exit your loop, instead of reading data to the memoryStream.

Try this:

```
while(true)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    conn.ReadTimeout = 15000000;
    count = istream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    if (count == 0)
        break;

    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}

istream.Close();

byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
var workBook = new XLWorkbook(memoryStream);
var workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.First()
```

Also close your istream after the loop, otherwise downloaded file might get truncated and that might be the reason why you are getting "Data is corrupted" error.

Comment: Thank you.I have updated my code as mentioned in the above comments. and my issue is not fixed. I have attached the screen shot of error that I am getting with the question.

Comment: @vijesh The line that follows your Exception window seems to go off the screen and does not in fact point at any of the code you are showing. IE the problem isn't in any code you are showing.