# Can I do something to increase the chances of files being correctly transmitted via FTP?

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm using the commands below to transmit compressed (.zip) files to a test FTP server. This works well at least with small files.
But after trying out a big file manually (aka with a tool) I saw that the real target FTP has a problem there as those files are ALWAYS corrupted (thus they can't be extracted any longer).

As the data I need to transfer is essential my question here would be: Is there anything I can do to increase the chances that the files I'm transmitting are transmited correctly (aka uncorrupted) ?

*As a note here: The small files I tested the code below with are just 1-3 MB in size while the big files I will need to transfer soon are 110-200 MB in size.*

*A thing to add also is that I'm not sure how likely it is that bytes "fall" aka 0 become 1 during the transfer or vice versa. Thus also things that make this less likely would be one of the points looked for. If it is possible at all.*

```
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}/{1}", ftpUrl, ftpFileName));
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpRequest.Credentials = ftpCredentials;

        int bufferLength = 2048;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        int contentlength;

        using (FileStream originalStream = (new FileInfo(compressedFile)).OpenRead())
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream targetStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    contentlength = originalStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                    while (contentlength != 0)
                    {
                        targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentlength);
                        contentlength = originalStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                -----
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK to me except this statement.

*targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentlength);*

Here you need to check how many bytes are actually written by "Write". If the
number of bytes written is less than countlength, then you should Write the
remaining data.I recommend you to add debug prints for contentlength and the
number of bytes actually written by Write function.

Comment: So you mean like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175874/get-file-size-on-an-ftp-in-c-sharp ? getting the size on the ftp server and counting also how many bytes were read from the local file and comparing those two?

Comment: No, I mean, check the return value of  Write operation.                            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentlength);

Comment: The .Write does not have any return value as far as I'm aware? (only .Read has)